Can this matrix problem be formulated as an ILP (or using constraint programming)?
Given an $n$ by $n$ binary matrix, I want to find the smallest number of bits that need to be flipped to reduce the rank of the matrix over the field of integers mod 2. I don't think there is a fast algorithm so I was hoping it could be formated as an integer linear programming problem (or cpsat in ortools). But I am not sure if the rank restriction allows that.

Might it be the case that the original matrix is not full rank?

@MarkL.Stone Yes. Although if that makes things more difficult we can assume it is full rank to start with.

Do you know a maximum rank submatrix going in?

Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4989469/number-of-bits-flips-needed-to-reduce-the-rank-of-a-binary-matrix

Assume that the original binary matrix $A$ has full rank. Let $x_{ij}\in\left\{ 0,1\right\} $
be a decision variable indicating whether we flip the bit $A_{ij}$
($x_{ij}=1$) or not ($x_{ij}=0$). Let $y_{ij}\in\left\{ 0,1\right\} $ (decision variable)
be the value of the $(i,j)$ bit in the modified matrix. Our first
set of constraints defines $y.$ For all $i,j\in\left\{ 1,\dots,n\right\} $
\begin{align*}
y_{ij} & =\left(1-A_{ij}\right)x_{ij}+A_{ij}\left(1-x_{ij}\right)\\
 & =A_{ij}+x_{ij}-2A_{ij}x_{ij}.
\end{align*}
The objective, to flip as few bits as possible, is simply
$$
\min\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{ij}.
$$
Given the assumption that $A$ has full rank, we are guaranteed a
rank reduction as long as a nonzero binary vector $z$ exists such
that $Yz\equiv0\ (\textrm{mod }2),$ where $Y$ is the modified matrix. We make the entries $z_{i}$
binary variables and assert the constraint
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}z_{i}\ge1
$$
to ensure that $z\neq0.$
What remains is to force $Yz\equiv0\ (\textrm{mod }2).$ For that
we introduce nonnegative integer variables $w_{i}$ and the constraints
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n}y_{ij}z_{j}=2w_{i}\quad\forall i.
$$
The products on the left need to be linearized, leading to more binary
variables $u_{ij}$ (representing the product $y_{ij}z_{j}$) with
the constraints
\begin{align*}
u_{ij} & \le y_{ij}\\
u_{ij} & \le z_{j}\\
u_{ij} & \ge y_{ij}+z_{j}-1.
\end{align*}
The congruence constraint now becomes
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n}u_{ij}=2w_{i}.
$$

If turns out that in the full rank case you only ever need to flip one bit so this is the easy case sadly.

If you know the rank going in is $r<n,$ you can modify the approach above by finding $n - r + 1$ different $z$ vectors satisfying $Yz^{(k)} \equiv 0$ along with mutual orthogonality constraints $z^{(k)}$$'z^{(j)} \equiv 0$ for $k\neq j.$ You are solving for an orthogonal basis of the null space of $Y$ and requiring it contain at least $n-r+1$ basis vectors.

That sounds like a good idea.
